# Difference betwen IIS 7 and ASP.NET MVC Client Caching

Tags: caching, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I would like to enable caching on an MVC Web site, there are several recommendations  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache
on using IIS Administration or Web.config to add the  entry but I am confused.

1)
**Is there any difference between these 2, can I just choose IIS Content Expiration and not the Web.config setting:**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image: IIS Content Expiration]

2)
**What is Output Caching, how is it different from Content Expiration?**

[image: Output Caching]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With content expiration it instructs the browser to cache the content while with output caching it caches the content on the server in order to run the code that generates the content less frequently and serve previously generated content from the cache which reduces the load on the server